# osCommerce Product state updater

Tags: excel, e-commerce, oscommerce

Does anybody know is there any tool that allows to automatically update products' prices and quantities saved in osCommerce DB from table-prices in Excel format?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Easy Populate or Smooth Populate will do the job:

[Smooth populate contribution](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/6835)

Comment: You will have to edit the contribution if you want to include product_model for each product item.